# Query para inserir numa tabela SQLServer

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

SqlServer, dada uma tabela com os campos: id (int), nome (nvarchar) e nascimento (smallDateTime)

Como posso escrever uma query para inserir nesta tabela e depois consultar estes dados de todos os registros da tabela.

Id: 000015
Nome: José
Nascimento: 2001

Comment: usando o comando `INSERT INTO`

Comment: aqui tem a documentação explicando e alguns exemplos que vão ajudar: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir um dado especifico utilize o **INSERT**:

```
INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (id,nome,nascimento)
VALUES (000015,'José',2001)
```

Para consultar todos os dados de um tabela utilize o **SELECT**:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela
```